# Add column to SQL query

Tags: postgresql

There is some select

```
SELECT column1, 
COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type1Count,
COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type2' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type2Count,
COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type3' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type3Count
FROM Yourtable 
GROUP BY column1
```

help me please, how i can add column0 which values corresponds to column1 in select query, some thing like that

```
SELECT column0, column1, 
COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type1Count,
COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type2' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type2Count,
COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type3' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type3Count
FROM Yourtable 
GROUP BY column1
```

but my variant is not work...

Comment: i need unique result from column1, if i did SELECT column0, column1, … GROUP BY column0, column1 result of this query is all data, but i need unique column1 like in firest example.

Answer (score 1):

When you are selecting the exact value of some columns, and aggregating (e.g. `COUNT()`, `SUM()`) on others, you need to tell the database which is which in the `GROUP BY` clause.

If you say:

```
GROUP BY column0, column1
```

Then for every unique combination of `column0` and `column1`, you will get an extra row of results, with the `COUNT()` expressions calculated across all the rows in the table for that combination.

If you only want one row for each distinct value of `column1`, you need to instead tell the database which value of `column0` you are interested in. For instance, you might ask for the minimum value of `column0` for each `column1` with this:

```
SELECT MIN(column0), column1 ... GROUP BY column1
```

Which means:

- I want one row for each distinct value of ... (`GROUP BY ...`)

  - ... `column1` (`... column1`)
- For each row, show me (`SELECT`):

  - The minimum value of `column0` in that group
  - The value of `column1` which will be the same for everything in that group

Comment: it's nearly result, but now i see in result column0 as i need, and don't see corresponding column1...

Comment: i try

SELECT MIN(column0), 
COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type1' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type1Count,
COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type2' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type2Count,
COUNT(CASE column2 WHEN 'type3' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Type3Count
FROM Yourtable 
GROUP BY column1

Comment: SELECT MIN(column0), MIN(column1) - worked for me!!!! If it's correct query this is what i need! :)

Comment: Your `SELECT` list doesn't contain `column1`. The results contain whatever columns you ask for in the `SELECT` list. I've edited slightly.

Comment: You don't need a `MIN()` around the thing you're grouping by - there's no "minimum" to take, because you have a different row for every distinct value.